# SQLite values not updating

Tags: python, sqlite, debugging

I want to insert this line 882,883 into sqlite3, but I don't get  any error in the try catch, and I don't see any row being added in the database in DB Browser for SQLite.

```
# Will add a new game into the database with players
def add_a_game(self, gameName, player1ID, player2ID):
    try:
        # Set the connection of the database
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("phylib.db")
        
        # Make an object for the cursor
        cursor2 = self.connection.cursor()
        print("Cursor2.connection() is " + str(cursor2.connection))

        print("conns1 is " + str(self.connection))
        print("cursor2 is " + str(cursor2))
        
        cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO Game (GAMENAME) VALUES (?)", (gameName,))
        cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO Game (GAMENAME) VALUES (?)", (the_game_id,))
        self.connection.commit()

    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('SQLite error: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
        print("Exception class is: ", er.__class__)
        print('SQLite traceback: ')

    print("test:")
    print(gameName)

    # Get the_game_id from the id of the last row of the cursor
    the_game_id = cursor2.lastrowid
    self.connection.commit()
    self.connection.close()

    self.connection = sqlite3.connect("phylib.db")

    # Make an object for the cursor
    cursor3 = self.connection.cursor()

    # Insert and assign a game ID to each player
    print(the_game_id)
    cursor3.execute("INSERT INTO Player (GAMEID, PLAYERNAME) VALUES (?, ?)", (the_game_id, player1ID))
    cursor3.execute("INSERT INTO Player (GAMEID, PLAYERNAME) VALUES (?, ?)", (the_game_id, player2ID))

    self.connection.commit()
    self.connection.close()

    return the_game_id
```

I’ve directly copied the insert statement at line 883 in the database and the row was added but nothing happens. I’m trying to make the sql statement work and have its values update accordingly. Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Here's my output, even when I'm adding a row it only stays as 1:

[image]

Comment: `the_game_id` is the ID for `'Games_02'`, not `gameName`.

Comment: Oh okay, I changed 'Games_02' to gameName on 

 cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO Game (GAMENAME) VALUES (?)", (gameName,))
 cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO Game (GAMENAME) VALUES ('Games_02')")

But nothing happened in the sqlite still?

Comment: Why are you inserting the same thing twice?

Comment: Can you remove all the commented code that seems to be left over from earlier attempts? It's cluttering up the question.

Comment: Oh would it be better to use the _game_id for that instead? 

Also sure, i've updated the code without those comments now. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're inserting two rows in games. Which one should `the_game_id` refer to?

Comment: the_game_id refers to the occurrence of game at that point (For example Game 1, Game 2, etc). This whole code is for a pool game program where it lets 2 players play against each other.

Comment: There's one game with two players, so you should only insert into `Game` once, then insert into `Players` twice with that same game ID.